# Oracle pl/sql to check if digits in a number is sequential

Tags: numbers, sequence, digit

I would need a Oracle pl/sql program to  check if a 9 digit number is in sequence( for e.g 0123456789,123456789,345678901, 456789012, 567890123 etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
 declare
  type t_num is table of number;
  t           t_num := t_num(1, 234, 5678, 43231567);
  first_digit number;
  leng        number;
  numb        number;
begin

  for i in t.first .. t.last loop
    first_digit := substr(t(i), 1, 1);
    leng        := length(t(i));
    numb        := first_digit;
    for j in 1 .. leng - 1 loop
      numb := numb || (first_digit + j);
    end loop;
    if t(i) = numb then
      dbms_output.put_line(numb);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```